# What's the diff between a build system and CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation

Like ant and bamboo, what's the diff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Continuous Integration requires a Build System to make sure that updates to the codebase build properly. CI is basically a system and method that pulls together other technologies, one of which is build, so that CI can happen.

So instead of ant and bamboo, the question is more like: What's the difference between an apple and a fruit salad? Again, none. One is part of the other. (Assuming you're always gonna have apples in your fruit salad ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A very short overview:

A *build system* builds the code on demand (ant).

A *continuous integration system* such as jenkins, builds the system e.g at each source code check in / commit, runs all unit test cases, and reports build or unit test failures, e.g. per email to the developper.
Such a system uses the build system (ant), but uses other systems too, (code coverage tool, etc.)